# An internal error occurred while linting the URL. Like button not working. Link not recognised

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, facebook-like

My blog link suddenly stopped being recognised on facebook (www.makeupbydyna.com). I can post it, but it will look like text, not with a thumbnail or anything of the sort. The like button is not working either. I have tried going on Facebook's Debugger and it says "An internal error occurred while linting the URL." I have tried filing a bug report but the "create button" is nowhere visible. How do I fix this error?

Comment: first step in these types of errors is to see if you have errors in your page markup code, by using the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). It appears you have several, some of which may be the cause for this behavior.